# PHP upload file fails in iframe

Tags: php, iframe, file-upload

I have an html page which POSTS files to a PHP backend - either using Ajax or through a hidden iframe.

Using Ajax I can upload files up to the limits set in my .htaccess (10M)

When I use IE - files above 2M are rejected with "Error 1:The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini".

It's as if requests passed with

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7db16f8c3114c
```

See a different PHP.INI setting than those that are

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

This is especially troublesome since IE cannot use XHR - so a large part of my users can't upload large files.

Any idea why this is happening?

Technical details:

- Server: Linux, Apache, PHP 5.2.17
- PHP ini settings (set in .htaccess, and checked using phpinfo):

  - upload_max_filesize 10M
  - post_max_size 10M
  - memory_limit 24M
- HTML Form enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: same here... have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the backend doesn't use ini_set to change the upload limit again. Also make sure that the .htaccess file is in the right directory.

Comment: Thanks - I wrote the backend, so no in_set.

Answer (score 0):

...and make sure to change both of the php.ini files..

The one in the Apache folder, and the one in the PHP folder..

Comment: I have no control over php.ini, as I am on a shared host. the .htaccess overrides the php.ini settings, and works as far as I can tell by calling ini_get and by looking a phpinfo.